# Let $f:\mathbb{Q}\to \mathbb{R}$, $f(p/q)=a^{p/q}$ such that $a>1$. Prove that $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=1$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I need to solve that problem. I tried proving instead $\lim_{x\to \infty}a^{1/x}=1$. But the complete proble say:
Let $f:\mathbb{Q}\to \mathbb{R}$, with $f(p/q)=a^{p/q}$ such that a>1. Prove that $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=1$ and conclude:

1. For all $b\in\mathbb{R}$, exists $\lim_{x\to b} f(x)$.
2. If $b\in \mathbb{Q}$ then $\lim_{x\to b} f(x)=f(b)$.
3. $a^x \cdot a^y =a^{x+y}$
4. If $x<y$ then $a^x < a^y$.

I use the fourth point but the problem tells me that i need to conclude it from the first statement. I really don't know how to proceed, may something like $\varepsilon -\delta$.
I'll apreciate your help.

Comment: Using my powers of mind reading to understand what the author meant, I _guess_ that for some reason, between point 2. and point 3., $x$ and $y$ suddenly became real. Or something. Showing that 3. and 4. holds for rational $x, y$ is almost trivial. Showing that they hold for real $x$ and $y$ (with $f$ and limits being used to define $a$ raised to a real number, and already knowing that they hold for rational exponents) would be a more suitable exercise at this stage.